# Htaccess redirect or rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I'm in the process of testing a site at a preview URL until the DNS transfers over. I'm previewing the site at `http://IP_ADDRESS/~name/`.

All of my images that have been uploaded in the CMS are listed like `<img src="/uploads/images/">`.

But this doesn't work while i'm on the preview URL. So ideally I need to redirect `/uploads/*` to `/~name/uploads/*`

I was wondering if this should be a redirect or a rewrite in htaccess and what the rule might be?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code you'll need in your .htaccess under DOCUMENT_ROOT:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^uploads/ ~name%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

Comment: Like this? `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymlinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^uploads/ ~name%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
</IfModule>`

Comment: Thanks man. For some reason they're not working on my server, which is very strange. :/

Comment: Do you have mod_rewrite and .htaccess enabled? and what URI did you try?